# Javascript Regex Not Matching As Excepted

Tags: javascript, regex

My regex:

```
openchild\(\'(.*)\'\)
```

doesn't match

```
openchild('text.php?textID=1',screen.width/2,800)
```

Full code:

```
$('a:contains("Edit")').each(function (index) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href'); //example - javascript: openchild('text.php?textID=1',screen.width/2,800)
    var r = /openchild\(\'(.*)\'\)/;
    var match = r.exec(href);
    $(this).attr('href', match[1]);
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
})
```

I tried different combinations like

```
var r = /openchild\('(.*)'\)/;
```

But no luck, [fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/6txoa0rh/)

Comment: Remove `'`s, or at least the second one. What do you want to get?

Comment: Why? Because your regex only matches the url but not the other parameters: https://regex101.com/r/3gr3Fu/1

Comment: Please only use the title of the question for a brief description of the issue. Examples and description should be in the body. Your example string is not copyable as is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need to extract url. Don't think I need to remove it

Comment: Then remove `\)`, https://regex101.com/r/3gr3Fu/2

Comment: Change `(.*)'` to `([^']+)` that will capture all non-quote characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex needs to account for the parameters beyond the first parameter of `openchild(...)`

Here's a working example for you :)

https://jsfiddle.net/q8Lu27wm/

```
$('a:contains("Edit")').each(function (index) {
    
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    
    var regex = /openchild\(\'(.*)\'.*\)/;
    
    var match = href.match(regex);
    var openChildUrl = match[1]; // first parameter
    
    $(this).attr('href', openChildUrl);
    
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
})
```